# Hash form validator always return error in Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu

That is my hash element:

```
$antiCSRF = new Zend_Form_Element_Hash(array('name' => 'hash'));
$antiCSRF->setTimeout(60)
   ->setSalt($securityRandomGenerator->generateString(1, 15))
   ->initCsrfValidator()
   ->initCsrfToken();
$antiCSRF->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));
```

But always hash validator return this message:

> The two given tokens do not match

I move my application from Windows host to Kubuntu host. On my Windows host hash element work perfectly, but on Kubuntu host return always error message. I use normal post request(not ajax).

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of OP)*:

I have missing one JavaScript file, and hash validator always return error. That is very strange problem :).